# Alert when transaction received in wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Is there a way to receive an alert if a transaction is received into my wallet (i.e. if I receive moneroj)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not something you're looking for, but I've been using this Chrome browser extension which uses `monero-wallet-rpc` and notifies me of new incoming funds:

https://github.com/Monero-Monitor/monero-wallet-chrome